# Como crear un dataframe nuevo que incluya las variaciones porcentuales del periodo anterior en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

estoy trabajando con un df que trata acerca del tipo de cambio, lo que quiero hacer es calcular las variaciones SEMESTRALES ( de enero a junio y luego de junio a diciembre).
Esto fue lo que hice:

```
df_tc = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Cedres\Desktop\jede\Tipo-de-Cambio-mensual (1).xls", sheet_name= "Tipo de Cambio", header = 13)
df_tc = df_tc.iloc[:21,1:16]
df_tc.columns.values
df_tc["PSem1"] = (df_tc["Ene "] + df_tc["Feb"] + df_tc["Mar"] + df_tc["Abr"] + df_tc["May"] + df_tc["Jun"])/6
df_tc["PSem2"] = (df_tc["Jul"] + df_tc["Ago"] + df_tc["Sep"] + df_tc["Oct"] + df_tc["Nov"] + df_tc["Dic"])/6
df_tc["VSem"] = ((df_tc["Psem2"]-df_tc["PSem1"])/df_tc["PSem1"])*100
```

Pero al hacerlo me di cuenta que el resultado que me arroja es la varacion entre los semestres de un mismo año, y yo lo que quiero es con el semestre anterior(que no siempre es del mismo año).
Ejemplo: TcSem2(2002)- TcSem1(2002)/TcSem1(2002) y luego el siguiente dato seria TCSem1(2003)-TCSem2(2002)/TCSem2(2002).

Por las dudas, la variacion porcentual del TC se calcula, TCFinal - TCInicial / TCInicial

Si quieren el dataframe es este: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/154JrwpETumaUbPdF_b1mgzH94dFehMgw/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104892511677427503963&rtpof=true&sd=true

PD: se me ocurrio la forma de hacerlo relativamente sencilla que seria creando una lista para ir dividiendo y que quede.

Respecto a eso probe esto:

```
result = [None]*(len(lista1)+len(lista2))
result[::2] = lista1
result[1::2] = lista2

result
tc = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es simplemente la division y que me cree una columna aparte en el dataframe para graficarlo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preparación del dataframe

La excel que se enlaza en la pregunta no tiene una estructura apropiada para ser procesada con pandas. Para empezar contiene muchas filas y columnas en blanco (por motivos estéticos, para centrar la tabla, supongo). Esta es una imagen de cómo se ve en Excel:

[image: Imagen excel]

Nuestro primer trabajo será importarlo a pandas eliminando la información que no es pertinente para el problema, es decir, todas las filas en blanco al inicio, y la primera columna A, así como las columnas O y P que contienen estadísticas anuales.

Esta sería una forma de lograrlo:

```
df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv", index_col=1, skiprows=13, nrows=22).iloc[:, 1:-2]
```

El dataframe que obtenemos es este:

```
       Ene     Feb    Mar    Abr    May  ...    Ago    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dic
2000  11,67  11,72  11,82  11,87  11,94  ...  12,34  12,36  12,38  12,39  12,44
2001  12,56  12,58  12,78  12,90  13,06  ...  13,38  13,58  13,96  13,95  14,06
2002  14,34  14,64  15,22  16,37  17,05  ...  26,69  28,96  27,01  27,19  27,25
2003  27,82  28,50  28,73  28,76  29,16  ...  27,81  27,86  28,26  28,89  29,24
2004  29,42  29,52  29,61  29,65  29,76  ...  28,87  27,94  27,17  26,65  26,56
2005  25,53  24,93  25,52  25,21  24,48  ...  24,34  24,09  23,59  23,52  23,65
...
```

Pero sigue sin estar en el formato apropiado para calcular lo que queremos. El formato "rectangular" no es adecuado. Sería mejor un formato "vertical" en el que tengamos una columna para el año, otra para el mes, y otra para el tipo de cambio.

Esto se puede lograr así:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ["año", "mes", "cambio"]
```

Ahora el dataframe tiene este aspecto:

```
      año   mes cambio
0    2000  Ene   11,67
1    2000   Feb  11,72
2    2000   Mar  11,82
3    2000   Abr  11,87
4    2000   May  11,94
..    ...   ...    ...
256  2021   May  43,99
257  2021   Jun  43,60
258  2021   Jul  43,83
259  2021   Ago  43,22
260  2021   Sep  42,70
```

Finalmente, la columna "cambio" no contiene valores numéricos (aunque lo parezca), sino cadenas. Esto se debe al uso de la coma decimal en vez del punto. Es fácil de arreglar:

```
df.cambio = df.cambio.str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
```

## Cálculo de la variación porcentual semestral

Una vez tenemos los datos en "columna", lo que buscamos es:

- Por un lado hacer el promedio de 6 en 6 filas
- Por otro lado, obtener la diferencia entre cada uno de esos promedios con el anterior
- Y finalmente dividir esa diferencia entre el promedio de la fila anterior (y multiplicar por 100 para tener el porcentaje)

Obtener el promedio de las filas agrupadas de 6 en 6 puede hacerse con un `.groupby()` y un truco:

```
semestral = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//6).mean()
```

Este sería el dataframe `semestral` resultante:

```
     año     cambio
0   2000  11.845000
1   2000  12.348333
2   2001  12.873333
3   2001  13.755000
4   2002  15.905000
5   2002  26.621667
...
```

Fíjate que ha desaparecido la columna "mes" (porque pandas no pudo calcular su promedio al no ser una columna numérica). Y que la columna año muestra cada año duplicado, siendo la primera aparición del año la que correspondería al primer semestre y la segunda aparición la que correspondería al segundo semestre.

La operación `semestral.diff()` calcula la resta de cada fila menos la anterior. Podemos guardar eso en una columna auxiliar:

```
semestral["dif"] = semestral.cambio.diff()
```

Y finalmente dividimos cada entrada de la columna `"dif"` por la entrada `"cambio"` de la fila anterior (usamos `shift(1)` para desplazar la columna "cambio" y así acceder en cada fila al elemento anterior)

```
semestral["variacion"] = semestral.dif/semestral.cambio.shift(1)*100
```

El resultado se verá así:

```
    año     cambio       dif  variacion
0  2000  11.845000       NaN        NaN
1  2000  12.348333  0.503333   4.249332
2  2001  12.873333  0.525000   4.251586
3  2001  13.755000  0.881667   6.848783
4  2002  15.905000  2.150000  15.630680
...
```

Que se puede leer así. Para el primer semestre de 2000 no hay datos (sale NaN) porque no tenemos semestre anterior.

Para el segundo semestre de 2000, la diferencia con el anterior ha sido de 0.503333 (efectivamente, 12.348333-11.845), lo que significa un incremento del 4.249332% (efectivamente, eso es 0.503333/11.845). Y así sucesivamente.

## Ampliación de la respuesta

Si quieres volver a concatenar estos resultados al dataframe "rectangular" original como un par de columnas nuevas, podemos volver a convertir la columna "variacion" en dos columnas, una para cada semestre. Es un poco enrevesado, pero lo siguiente funcionará:

- Primero añadimos al dataframe `semestral` una columna llamada "semestre", inicialmente rellena con unos:

  ```
  semestral["semestre"] = 1
  ```
- Después cambiamos esos ceros por 1 o 2, según se trate del primer o segundo semestre de cada año. Para hacerlo de forma automatizada, agrupamos por año y ponemos en "semestre" la suma acumulada de esa columna (será 1 en el primer semestre, 1+1 en el segundo):

  ```
  semestral["semestre"] = semestral.groupby("año").semestre.cumsum()
  ```
- Finalmente creamos un índice de dos niveles (año y semestre) y efectuamos `unstack()` sobre la columna "variacion", para que el semestre pase de ser un nivel del índice, a las columnas:

  ```
  semestral = semestral.set_index(["año", "semestre"]).variacion.unstack()
  ```

Este será el resultado en el dataframe `semestral`:

```
semestre          1          2
año                           
2000            NaN   4.249332
2001       4.251586   6.848783
2002      15.630680  67.379231
2003       6.229262  -0.406648
2004       5.154151  -6.218346
```

Son los mismos datos de antes (bueno, nos hemos quedado solo con la variación porcentual y descartado el "dif"), pero organizados en tabla de modo que cada fila sea un año y cada columna un semestre de ese año.

En este formato es más sencillo agregarlo al dataframe original:

```
orig = pd.read_csv("datos.csv", index_col=1, skiprows=13, nrows=22).iloc[:, 1:-2]
orig[["Semestre1", "Semestre2"]] = semestral
```

Y ahora el resultado es una tabla rectangular igual a la que usamos como punto de partida, pero con dos columnas añadidas para la variación percentual por semestres:

```
       Ene     Feb    Mar    Abr  ...    Nov    Dic  Semestre1  Semestre2
2000  11,67  11,72  11,82  11,87  ...  12,39  12,44        NaN   4.249332
2001  12,56  12,58  12,78  12,90  ...  13,95  14,06   4.251586   6.848783
2002  14,34  14,64  15,22  16,37  ...  27,19  27,25  15.630680  67.379231
2003  27,82  28,50  28,73  28,76  ...  28,89  29,24   6.229262  -0.406648
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :D, el único inconveniente que tengo es a la hora de graficar, ya que al tener 2 valores de 2000, no queda bien representado, pero creo que puedo solucionarlo